# dynamic dependant drop using codeigniter hmvc is not working

Tags: ajax, codeigniter, drop-down-menu, hmvc

i'm trying populate all the course present in the database which has higher course_id than the selected one in first dropdown.

course.php (controller)

---

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Course extends MX_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this -> load -> model('course_model');
}

public function index() {        
    $data['courses'] = $this -> course_model -> get_course();
    $this -> load -> view('dropdisplay', $data);
}

public function get_next_course($course){
    $this->load->model('nextcourse_model');
    header('Content-Type: application/x-json; charset=utf-8');
    echo(json_encode($this->nextcourse_model->get_course($course)));
}    

}
```

course_model.php (model)

---

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Course_model extends CI_Model {

public function __construct() {
    $this -> load -> database(); 
    echo "course_model <br/><br/>";
}

function get_course() 
{

    $this -> db -> select('course_id, course_name');
    $query = $this -> db -> get('course');

    $courses = array();

    if ($query -> result()) 
    {   
        foreach ($query->result() as $course) 
        {
           $courses[$course -> course_id] = $course -> course_name;
        }
        return $courses;
    } 
    else 
    {
        return FALSE;
    }
}

}
?>
```

nextcourse_model.php (model)

---

```
<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Nextcourse_model extends CI_Model {

public function __construct() {
    $this->load->database();
    echo "nextcourse_model <br/><br/>";
}


function get_course($cour, $tree = null) {
    $this->db->select('course_id, course_name');
    $this-db->from('course');
    $this->db->where('course_id >', $cour);

    if ($tree != NULL) {
        $this->db->where('course_id', $cour);
    }

    $query = $this->db->get('course');
    $nextcourses = array();

    if ($query->result()) {
        foreach ($query->result() as $value) {
            $nextcourses[$value->course_id] = $value->course_name;
        }
        return $nextcourses;
    } else {
        return FALSE;
    }
}

}
?>
```

dropdisplay.php (view)

---

```
<html> 
<head>
    <title>Course</title>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
//            $(document).ready(function(){
        var course_id;
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#course').change(function() { 
                $("#whatnext > option").remove(); 
//                    course_id = $('#course').val();
                course_id = $('this').val();
            });
        });

        //$('#check').change(function(){
        // $("#whatnext > option").remove(); 
        //var course_id = $('#course').val();

        function getcondition(id)
        {
            if (id == 1)
            {    //alert(id);
//                    alert(course_id);
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "localhost/coursepath/course/get_next_course/" + course_id,     // passing this course_id to course controller
                    //data: '&course_id='+course_id,
                    success: function(nextcourses) 
                    {
                        alert(course_id);
                        $.each(nextcourses, function(id, course) 
                        {
                            var opt = $('<option />'); 
                            opt.val(id);
                            opt.text(course);
                            $('#whatnext').append(opt);
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
            else if (id == 2)
            {

//                    alert("course_id=" + course_id);
            }
        }

        // ]]>
    </script>
</head>
<body>        
    <?php $courses['#'] = 'Please Select'; ?>
    <label for="course">What am I: </label>
    <?php echo form_dropdown('course_id', $courses, '#', 'id="course"'); ?><br />




    <label for="next_course">Category: </label> 
    <select id="check" class="bot" onchange="getcondition(this.value);">
<!--        <select id="check" class="bot">            -->
        <option value="" selected=selected> Select Category</option>
        <option value="1"> Course</option>
        <option value="2"> Job</option>
    </select><br />        


    <?php $whatnext['#'] = 'Please Select'; ?> <br />    
    <label for="next_course">What I want to be: </label>
    <?php echo form_dropdown('stream_id', $whatnext, '#', 'id="whatnext"'); ?><br />
</body>
</html>
```